# How to "create spatial index while using" Modeler?

Tags: qgis, spatial-index

It was possible in previous QGIS version but since a while, if i add Create a spatial index in the modeler i get a warning :

> L'algorithme “Créer un index spatial” ne peut pas être exécuté dans un thread d'arrière-plan, il faut passer au thread principal pour cette étape.

Quick Translate :

> The “Create Spatial Index” algorithm cannot be executed in a background thread, you must switch to the main thread for this step.

So how to use Create a spatial index in the modeler now ?